# Understanding the output of AddHazard package

Tags: survival, regression-coefficients, hazard

In a cohort study, I am trying to assess the excess number of deaths in patients with a specific condition during follw-up. I am trying to do this by using an additive hazard model and am using the package AddHazard with the following model:

```
fit <- ah(surv(time,outcome)~exposure, ties=F, data=data, robust=F. 
summary(fit)
```

Result:
exposure 5.0e-04 (coef)

Unfortunently, I can't figure out what this tells me exactly. My time variable is in years. Does this mean that there is 5.0e-04 excess deaths per year in the exposure group 1?

I look forward to your comments?

Comment: Please can you include the output from `summary(fit)`

Comment: Without further information it would seem that for every 10,000 individuals with the exposure, you would expect 5 excess deaths per year due to that exposure, compared to if they were not exposed.